# How to access webpage from R

Tags: r, http, https

I am trying to access a webpage from `R` without any success -

```
> readLines('https://www.nseindia.com')
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
```

Below is my session information-

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows Server x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] httr_1.4.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.1 R6_2.4.1       tools_4.0.1    curl_4.3
```

I am using R in `Windows` from `Amazon AWS`.

However when I use the same code from my local `Mac`, I have no problem.

Any pointer how to resolve this issue will be highly helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

```
setInternet2(TRUE)
```

Or try to run R in administrator mode.

Comment: The setInternet2() function appears to be defunct. Running in Admin mode is not helping either